Can I thin over-thickened boiled linseed oil with unboiled linseed oil?
I have real boiled linseed oil.
It started off as just a bit thicker than raw, but  over the years it has thickened to the point  that it makes a film and is quite annoying to apply.
I was wondering if it is possible to thin it out with raw linseed oil. Will they mix properly and will the boiled base quicken the polymerization of the raw thinner?

Yes, there's no physical reason you can't mix the two together; all oils are miscible in this way.
However there are reasons you might not want to, there are other options to consider instead as I'll outline below.

Will they mix properly and will the boiled base quicken the polymerization of the raw thinner?

That's what it'll seem like. But do realise that the unoxidised molecules of raw oil are still present in the mixture so some of this will be simply the already well-oxidised oil molecules doing their initial 'drying' rather than every part of the oil oxidising at a consistent rate. In practice this may be too subtle a difference to be noticeable in woodworking applications, where the oil is basically in the wood and not on the surface.

I'm not sure if you already have the raw linseed oil, if you don't I would advise not getting any for this purpose. Get fresh BLO instead.
Raw linseed oil or flax-seed oil is of little to no practical use in a modern woodworking shop1 — we now know there are better options for everything it was formerly used for.
How to use the thickened BLO as-is
You can reduce viscosity of thicker oils by warming. Heating the oil up will make it flow better, so it'll be easier to apply; depending on just how far the oxidation has progressed it may improve things a lot or a little (in the temperature range that is practical here, it must remain cool enough that you don't scorch your fingers).
Warming the wood surface well is something you can do instead of, or in addition to, gentle warming of the oil. If you don't heat the oil, the thick oil will reduce viscosity the moment it touches the warmed wood (just like with epoxies).
But thickened oils are a good candidate for something I'm normally not a fan of in woodworking applications and that's dilution.
Dilution
You can easily and effectively thin any kind of thickened oil with small amounts of a suitable solvent, in practice in woodworking this means mineral spirits (UK: white spirit), a low-odour version of these, or real turpentine2.
Regardless of the one you pick it doesn't take a lot to make a surprisingly big difference to viscosity, so don't go into it thinking you'll need a mix that's 1/3 solvent. Perhaps 5% or less will be enough. If you want to proceed cautiously you can add the solvent drop by drop, shaking the mix container and see how things progress. A suitable mixing and storage container is a clean jar with a tight-fitting lid.
However, you can thin literally as much as you want — same as some people prefer to thin their homemade wiping varnish 1:1 or even 1:2 instead of the 2:1 (1/3 solvent) that others find acceptable. Just be aware that the more you thin the oil the less you're depositing on the surface with each application, so heavy dilution can make a profound difference to the overall finishing process since you have to apply more coats to get to the same point.

1 If you do have it already and you want to make it more practically useful in your shop, I would give serious consideration to converting some or all of it into homemade "BLO" with some cautious heating (in an open container on the stovetop). If working with the oil very hot fills you with trepidation another potential use is blending it with shellac to make a type of friction polish, especially useful if you are a woodturner.
2 Do note turps is the most toxic of these three, despite being from natural sources. But it's not so toxic that it should be discounted outright as an option; some people like to use it simply because they find its characteristic odour pleasant.
